# Problems importing Cocos 3.0 class into Cocos 2.X project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've had heaps of trouble importing OALSimpleAudio into my Cocos 2.X project.

The app is quite big.

What is the best way for me to import Cocos 3.0 into an existing project?

**The final error looks like this:**

[image]

---

**This is what I've done so far:**

1. The Cocos 3.0 Libraries stuff is brought into libs folder.
2. ARC flags are set for Cocos 3.0 files as this is a non-ARC project and Cocos 3.0 uses ARC.
3. Relevant frameworks used in Cocos 3.0 template put in for project.
4. Architecture problem appears when using simulator, complains for architecture i386. When I use an actual device (iPad) as opposed to simulator it complains for architecture armv7 in the exact same way as picture 3 above.

Comment: try using the official release and install instructions here http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/

Comment: This worked, thanks. 
I just had to make sure that all instances of the old SimpleAudioEngine were deleted and this standalone worked fine. Using this really reduced the complexity from dragging in the whole Cocos 3.0 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the official release and install instructions here kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone was sufficient.
Not using the whole Cocos 3.0 reduced the complexity of transition. However it was also necessary to make sure that all instances of the old audio engine were deleted - before then even though it ran without errors the audio didn't work.